# Measure of complement of union of nowhere dense set with positive measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, baire-category

The original question is:

Let $A$ be Lebesgue measurable in $\mathbb{R}$ with positive measure. Show that it is not true that there must exist a sequence $\{x_n\}^\infty_{n=1}$ such that the complement of $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(A+\{x_n\})$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is measure zero.

To disprove the statement, I want to take $A$ to be the fat rational set and argue that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, the complement of the set stated above must have positive measure.

Let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$, fix $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ and let
\begin{equation}
I_n=(q_n-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}},q_n+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+1}}).
\end{equation}
Let $G=\cup_nI_n$, and $A=[0,1]\setminus G$, then clearly any rationals cannot be in $A$ and it follows that $A$ is nowhere dense. It is easy to show that $A$ is Lebesgue measurable and has measure
\begin{equation}
m(A)= 1-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}=1-\epsilon\in(0,1),
\end{equation}
so $A$ satisfies the hypothesis of the question. Since $A$ is nowhere dense so $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(A+\{x_n\})$ is nowhere dense also for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

However, I found it difficult to prove that the complement of $\bigcup^\infty_{n=1}(A+\{x_n\})$ must have positive measure for arbitrary sequence $\{x_n\}$

Comment: Actually, once $A$ is measurable and $m(A)>0$, one *can* find a sequence such that the complement of $\cup_k(A+x_k)$ has zero Lebesgue measure (hint: by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem $A$ almost contains an open interval), so the statement of the "original question" is just false.

Comment: @fedja Hi, if $A$ has a positive measure, then for $\mu$-almost every $x \in A$, $x$ has the property that $A$ has a positive measure intersection $V$ with every open interval containing $x$, say $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$, $\delta > 0$. Let the sequence to be all rational number, then $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}(A+{q_n})$ will cover $\mathbb{R}$, and we have a complement which is a null set. Is this the idea how we solve this problem? Would you please give a rigorous proof or other related theorems? (I did not see the result "$A$ almost contains an open interval" in the Lebesgue differentiation theorem)

Comment: @Flashhh You are also confused a bit. We have not just positive measure, but measure that is almost $2\delta$, and that is essential. And yes, the enumeration of rationals will work, but the complement will not need to be empty, just a zero measure set ;-).

Comment: @fedja what do you mean by A contains almost an open interval?

Comment: Do you mean that there is a subset E of A such that $diam(E)=m(E)$

Comment: @BiplabDas For every $\varepsilon>0$, there is an interval $I$ such that the measure of $A\cap I$ is at least $(1-\varepsilon)|I|$

Comment: @fedja Yeah I get that. But what next how to show that there exist a sequence ${x_n}$ such that $A+{x_n}$ has full measure?

Comment: @BiplabDas Just enumerate the rationals, as suggested before. The complement will have $0$ density at each point (move the short "dense" interval so that the point is in the middle third), hence its measure is $0$.